# Facebook not taking my website pictures

Tags: wordpress, image

When I attempt to share my web site to face it solely fetch information no pictures owing to that I whenever transfer manual image to Facebook post. I'm thinking to set up WordPress. Here is screen print as post show on Facebook.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a screen print as you have describe.

Facebook fetches the image and title with meta tags.

For image to load it should have such structure in your website.

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/themes/xyz/images/example.jpg"/>`

If such meta tag is not present then this might be the issue.

So, you can add such meta tags on `wp_head()` hook so that it will be displayed in `<head>` of the website.

For example,

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_function', 10 );
function custom_function(){
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/themes/xyz/images/example.jpg"/>';
}
```